# How to loop single const for multiple time in NextJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, for-loop, next.js

I would like to print the `<Icon />` for 700 times on the same page. I'm new to NextJs. I use for loop to make it, and able to console.log, but I don't know how to print it. Anyone could help me? Appreciate it much.

Here my code is.

```
import React from 'react'
import { IoMdWoman } from 'react-icons/io'

const Icon = <IoMdWoman size={40} color='#E91E63' />

for (let i = 0; i < 700; i++) {
  console.log(Icon)
}

const test700 = () => {
  return (
    <ul>
      <li>{Icon}</li>
    </ul>
  )
}

export default test700
```

Comment: `return new Array(700).map(_=> <ul>
      <li>{Icon}</li>
     </ul>
  )`. use this as return value in your test700 function

Comment: You need to return an array of 700 elements. whereas you're just returning only one element.

Comment: @CodeManiac The OP likely wants 700 `<li>`s, not 700 `<ul>`s, if next.js uses jsx like react does...

Comment: @HereticMonkey ahh i guess you're right, next is a superset of react which has server side rendering capabilities as well, yeah in that case `<ul>` tag can be moved out of loop

Comment: `return <ul>{new Array(700).map(_=> <li>{Icon}</li>)}<\ul>`. if you need a list of 700 items. use this as return value in your test700 function

Comment: @CodeManiac No it's doesn't work.

Comment: @ThiagaRajServai Stack Overflow is not a code on demand service. CodeManiac has provided you with the code very kindly in their comments. You need to examine that code and figure out if it works for your circumstances and adjust it as needed. That's part of what being a programmer is all about. I know it's hard starting out, but the best thing to do is to take these nuggets of learning and work things out for yourself.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Appreciate for your efforts. Thanks. I'll find the solution by myself.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const array = Array(700).fill(undefined) // old syntax
// or
const array = [...Array(700)] // using spread syntax (produces the same as above)

const test700 = () => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {array.map(_=><li>{Icon}</li>)}
    </ul>
  )
}
```